# android connection

Tags: android, networking

Hi I'm using this snippet from [android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html)

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}
```

But when I interrupt the internet connection from my desktop it won't find that isn't connected,and try to connect. I'm running it in the Android emulator. My question:why it won't return false and still figures out that it is connected?if it was connected through 3D shouldn't it get the data?

Comment: y dont  u use xmpp connection...

Comment: ok i'm actually just making the first steps in android..What is that you are saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Networking {
 /*
 *@return boolean return true if the application can access the internet
 */
 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
     ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
           for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
              if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                 return true;
              }
           }
        }
     }
     return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the internet connection on your computer won't reflect changes on the emulator.

You will need to disable the internet directly from the emulator like you would do on a real phone:

`Settings -> Wireless and networks ->  Mobile Networks ->  Use packed data.`

(I suppose the path may vary from emulator to emulator depending of SDK version)

Answer (score 1):

public class HttpManager {

```
public static String getData(String uri) {

    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // Checks the user prefs and the network connection. Based on the result, decides
        // whether
        // to refresh the display or keep the current display.
        // If the userpref is Wi-Fi only, checks to see if the device has a Wi-Fi connection.
        if (WIFI.equals(sPref) && networkInfo != null
                && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            // If device has its Wi-Fi connection, sets refreshDisplay
            // to true. This causes the display to be refreshed when the user
            // returns to the app.
            refreshDisplay = true;
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.wifi_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // If the setting is ANY network and there is a network connection
            // (which by process of elimination would be mobile), sets refreshDisplay to true.
        } else if (ANY.equals(sPref) && networkInfo != null) {
            refreshDisplay = true;

            // Otherwise, the app can't download content--either because there is no network
            // connection (mobile or Wi-Fi), or because the pref setting is WIFI, and there
            // is no Wi-Fi connection.
            // Sets refreshDisplay to false.
        } else {
            refreshDisplay = false;
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.lost_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```